visualization a Decision Trees with pydotplus
in a project of Decision Tree
I wrote this code, but it gets a specific error and I consulted with AI , the problem is not solved, you can see where the problem comes from.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import preprocessing
df = pd.read_csv('E:\mostafa folder\mashin learning\S5recommendersystems\Files\drug200.csv')
df.head()
df.describe()
df.columns
x = df[['Age', 'Sex', 'BP', 'Cholesterol', 'Na_to_K']].values
x
y = df[['Drug']].values
y
from sklearn import preprocessing
le_sex = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le_sex.fit(['F','M'])
x[:,1] = le_sex.transform(x[:,1]) 


le_BP = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le_BP.fit([ 'LOW', 'NORMAL', 'HIGH'])
x[:,2] = le_BP.transform(x[:,2])


le_Chol = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le_Chol.fit([ 'NORMAL', 'HIGH'])
x[:,3] = le_Chol.transform(x[:,3]) 

x[0:4]
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=3)

print('shape of train : ',x_train.shape,y_train.shape)
print('shape of test : ',x_test.shape,y_test.shape)
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="entropy", max_depth = 6)

tree.fit(x_train,y_train)
pretree = tree.predict(x_test)

print (pretree [0:5])
print (y_test [0:5])
from sklearn import metrics
print("DecisionTrees's Accuracy: ", metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, pretree))
from  io import StringIO
import pydotplus
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
%matplotlib inline 
dot_data = StringIO()
featuresnames = df.columns
filename = 'mosi.png'

out = export_graphviz(tree,feature_names = featuresnames)
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz

dot_data = StringIO()
filename = 'ee.png'
#featurenames = df.columns[0:5]

out = export_graphviz(tree, feature_names=df.columns[0:5], out_file=dot_data, class_names= np.unique(y_train), filled=True, special_characters=True, rotate=False)

graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
graph.write_png(filename)
img = mpimg.imread(filename)
plt.figure(figsize=(100, 200))
plt.imshow(img, interpolation='nearest')


And this problem is taken from this line
out = export_graphviz(tree, feature_names=df.columns[0:5], out_file=dot_data, class_names= np.unique(y_train), filled=True, special_characters=True, rotate=False)
<module 'sklearn.tree' from 'C:\\Users\\PARDAZESHGARA\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\tree\\__init__.py'> is not an estimator instance.

help me guys!!!!

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
